# Cats regularly defecate in my garden. Is there really nothing I can do about it?

Tags: lawn, domestic-animals

I have a small lawn area and cats from the neighborhood regularly come into my garden to defecate.

The neighbor says you can do nothing about it, just clean the poop away. All products that promise relief bring nothing according to him.

Comment: There are some suggestions [here](https://www.countryliving.com/uk/wildlife/pets/a32402647/how-stop-cats-pooping-in-garden/). Or get a dog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your grass isn't kept short, then yes,most cats will use it as a toilet, but if it is kept  short, un-neutered toms will be  the only ones that will do this.

The only system I've seen that works really well is one an electrical engineer friend built for himself - he attached a motion sensor system to a sprinkler set up in the middle of his small lawn, so whenever there was movement, the sprinkler turned on for a short period and any cats left immediately. There may, by now,be a proprietary setup you can buy that does a similar thing, not sure.

Comment: Yes, there is a proprietary sensor/sprinkler setup, but possibly only in the US/Canada (hope UK users can see this site): https://gadgets-reviews.com/review/832-best-motion-activated-sprinklers.html I assume if it's on 24 hours a day then a human will also set it off, too.

Comment: Yes - its important to remember to switch off the power or the tap before venturing into the area covered by the sprinkler yourself!

Comment: I confirm that the store bought motion-detected sprinkler works to prevent cats from defecating in a particular spot. I only needed to have it set up for a couple months a few years ago, and it seems to have worked as a permanent deterrent.